# Suprenum of a collection of $L^p$ functions

Tags: measure-theory

For measure space $(X, M, \mu)$, let $A=\{f_n\}$ be an at most countable collection of positive real functions on $X$. Denote the suprenum of all members of $A$ by $g$ (i.e. $g(x)= \sup_{f \in A}f(x)$). Fix $p>0$.

1. If each member of A is an element of $L^p(\mu)$, is the $g$ inside $L^p(\mu)$?
2. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Assume that $\|f\|_p \leqslant \epsilon$ for every $f\in A$. Is it true that $\|g\|_p \leqslant \epsilon$?

Comment: If your collection is uncountable, $g$ might not even be measurable.

Comment: You are definitely correct. I will change the post.

Comment: Let $g_n = \{ f_1, \cdots, f_n\}$ and use monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: $f_n = \chi_{[0, n]}\frac{\varepsilon}{n} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ disproves both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first property is false, take $p=1$ and $f_n(x)=1_{[-n,n]}(x)$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then you have $g(x)=1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.